# How to confirm a Skype meeting?

Tags: american-english, questions, formal-language, informal-language

I want to ask someone if "Thursday" is a good day for a skype meeting.

How should I ask?

1. Is Thursday at 10am a good day? (sounds wrong)
2. I just want to confirm our meeting at XYZth at 11am. Will you be available? (sounds weird)

Update:

I already sent an email for this person and he didn't reply yet. 
I just want to make sure that he saw my email and confirm the meeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few I can think of if you are asking for the first time:

- Are you free on Thursday at 10am? - What time on Thursday are free?
- How about Thursday at 10am? - Are you free any other time on Thursday?
- Can we speak on Thursday at 10am? - At what time can we speak then?

For confirmation (at least what I've heard):

- Is everything in order (as planned) for Thursday?
- Are we still okay on Thursday?

You could eventually write and ask him why he didn't reply:

- You didn't answer my email, I'm worried, so do we meet on Thursday at 10am or not?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already sent an email for this person and he didn't reply yet. I just want to make sure that he saw and confirm.

Comment: @Eds Include that in your question, please!

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks! One more question. Is "I would like to confirm our meeting on Thursday. Is this date and time good for you?" a nice way to ask?

Comment: @Eds In this case you're stating that the meeting will definitely be, but you are not asking the receiver to confirm it.